# Frequency detection in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python

I was tasked with developing an ML algorithm to predict machine failure based on vibration analysis.  To do so, I must do the following:

1. Detect different frequencies from an input signal

   - Input can be any sample frequency from 1hz to 100 kHz
2. Train an ML algorithm to detect the faulty frequencies

My current approach is to take a Fourier transform of the input signal, and then feed the result into a linear classifier (LDA).

What would be some good methodologies about approaching this?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Are there particular frequencies that you expect to be particularly indicative of impending failure?

Comment: Since this is all very vague at the moment it is hard for anyone to say what you should or should not do. Have you tried your approach and got some results to show us?